# Take Picture Using UIImagePickerController with Custom Zoom

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, camera, custom-controls, zooming

I created a custom Camera Control with overlay ...

Now i am zooming image by using Slider by ..

```
imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(initialTransform, 

MainSlider.value, MainSlider.value);
```

where initialTransform is the initial image transformation ...
MainSlider is slider , which i use to get zoom level from 1 to 4
So each time when i increase image using Slider ... I refer initialTransform and zoom accordingly Slider value ...

I am able to zoom by doing this .. But when i capture photo using

```
[imagePickerController takePicture];
```

It gives me Original Picture only .. does not give me any EditedImage ...

This original image is same as without zoom ...
I want to get Image which was zoomed ...
Means whatever showing in screen ...

I try to find a lot for this,,,, I know we can use GetScreenCapture()
but it can be cause of rejection of app and also it lower down the image quality ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the same transform to the image after it has been captured. Setting `cameraViewTransform` will only affect the display, as you've noticed. When you apply a uniform scaling transform (e.g. to zoom) this is a digital zoom. You are not increasing the pixel resolution. You'll get the pic back from the camera and then you can crop/scale it to the size you want when processing the image. You should do your processing on a background thread to minimize disrupting the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .... You are completey right ... i am just using transformation to View ... I believe Uniform Scaling transform is only done by AffineTransformation , Which is only available for iOS 4...Please let me know if you find any source of information for me ....